# Pagination in product listing page fails

Tags: pagination

In website on Magento 2.1.5, in any category I have added around 80 products. 
When I am opening product listing page in any category; default its showing 9 products in grid. 
If I change limit to 15, I can see products are appearing in grid. 
Once I change limit to 30, site is showing blank page. 
Can anyone suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Check you system log for errors.  It is located at /var/log/system.log. Scroll to the bottom for the latest errors.  Then do a google search on that error, or include it in your question here on stack exchange.

Comment: Thanks Brain for a quick information. I will check the log and add it.